# How can I capture stdout and stderr from a WebAssembly module generated by Emscripten in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, webassembly

I have the following C++ code

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Which I compile with

```
emcc -s ENVIRONMENT=shell -s WASM=1 -s MODULARIZE=1 main.cpp -o main.js
```

The command above generates a `main.js` and a `main.wasm`.

Then, using `isolated-vm`

```
npm install isolated-vm
```

I have the following code in JavaScript

```
const fs = require("fs");
const ivm = require("isolated-vm");
const isolate = new ivm.Isolate({ memoryLimit: 128 });

const context = isolate.createContextSync();
const jail = context.global;

jail.setSync("global", jail.derefInto());

const hostile = isolate.compileScriptSync(fs.readFileSync("main.js", "utf8"));

hostile.run(context).catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

If I run

```
node index.js
```

It runs without any erros, but no stdout/stderr.

My question is: Using `isolated-vm`, how can I capture stdout and stderr **to** a JavaScript variable?

I searched for code on GitHub, but what I found didn't work.

---

EDIT

If I compile with these flags

```
emcc -s ENVIRONMENT=node -s WASM=1 main.cpp -o main.js && node main.js
```

It shows "Hello World!" in the terminal, however, if I try to run it as showed in the `index.js` above, I get the error

```
Error: not compiled for this environment (did you build to HTML and try to run it not on the web, or set ENVIRONMENT to something - like node - and run it someplace else - like on the web?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can get you half-way there. I would consider this a bug in `isolated-vm`, because if you pass vanilla javascript, it works as well as in the node version.

```bash
$ em++ main.cpp -o main.js -s WASM=0 -s ENVIRONMENT=node && node main.js
Hello World!
$ em++ main.cpp -o main.js -s WASM=1 -s ENVIRONMENT=node && node main.js
Hello World!
$ em++ main.cpp -o main.js -s WASM=0 -s ENVIRONMENT=shell && node index.js
Hello World!
$ em++ main.cpp -o main.js -s WASM=1 -s ENVIRONMENT=shell && node index.js
$
```

So, the only case where this is not working, is when main.js uses wasm internally.

Furthermore, when you actually run it in the v8 shell, it works as expected:

```bash
$ em++ main.cpp -o main.js -s WASM=1 -s ENVIRONMENT=shell && v8 main.js
Hello World!
```

In order to get to this point, I had to modify `index.js` a bit:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const ivm = require("isolated-vm");
const isolate = new ivm.Isolate({ memoryLimit: 128 });

const context = isolate.createContextSync();
const jail = context.global;

jail.setSync("global", jail.derefInto());
jail.setSync("print", function (...args) {
  console.log(...args);
});

readbuffer = function(f) {
 return fs.readFileSync(f);
};

jail.setSync("readbuffer", readbuffer);

const hostile = isolate.compileScriptSync(fs.readFileSync("main.js", "utf8"));

hostile.run(context).catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

Emscripten-compiled modules prefer to use the `print` function before the `console.log` function. Also, for some reason, the `read` function wasn't setup for `main.js` to use, and neither was `readbuffer`. You need one of them, in order to read `main.wasm` off the disk.

As a nitpick, I know the original example was hostile, but you should change the name of the variable now, as this is benign :)

I'll keep an eye on the question and try some more stuff, as well as hoping a more experienced answerer comes along, but for me, you should ask the maintainers of `isolated-vm` why it behaves like this.

Comment: Thank you. Just a question, will stdout go to `jail.setSync("print", function (...args)`? Because I thought that stdout got wrapped into `console.log`, not `print` and stderr to `console.error`.

Comment: `stdout` goes to `print` first, and if it doesn't find `print`, then it tries `console`, but that's an Emscripten thing, `emcc` puts the logic there. You can try it with `WASM=0`, to see what it does when it works.

Comment: Got it, thank you!